# CKEditor in BoltCMS cuts tags

Tags: php, ckeditor, bolt-cms

CKEditor in BoltCMS by default not save tag `<section>`.
Is it possible to set some settings for accept this tag and where I can do this in BoltCMS?

UPD: also CKEditor cuts data-attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution - need to add necessary tags and attributes to `app/config/config.yml` to the option `htmlcleaner`.